# Merge dynamic object arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-merge

I'm trying to dynamically build an object with key:[value array], however using different methods I keep ending up with a singular item in the value array (where in the response there are multiple values).

Psuedocode:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    var myObject = {};
    $.ajax('http://the.url.com', {
        type: "GET",
        success: function (res) {
            $(res).each(function (i, v) {
                    var name = v.name;
                    var id = v.id;
                    // create object with building block and tech id to associate techs to BBs
                    myObject[name] = new Array();
                    myObject[name].push(id);
                });
        },
        error: function (xhr) {}
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
{
    key1: ["value1c"]
    key2: ["value2a"]
    key3: ["value3b"]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    key1: ["value1a", "value1b","value1c"]
    key2: ["value2a"]
    key3: ["value3a", "value3b"]
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you match "key1", "key2", "key3"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the existing array with a new one for each key, then pushing the latest one in with the following line:

```
 myObject[name] = new Array();
```

Try adding a check to avoid overwriting:

```
 myObject[name] = myObject[name] || new Array();
```

Comment: Concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to check if `myObject[name]` already exists before creating a new one. Because if you create a new one each time, it will be overridden

```
var myFunction = function () {
  var myObject = {};
  $.ajax('http://the.url.com', {
    type: "GET",
    success: function (res) {
      $(res).each(function (i, v) {
        var name = v.name;
        var id = v.id;
        // create object with building block and tech id to associate techs to BBs
        if (!myObject[name]) {
          myObject[name] = new Array();
        }
        myObject[name].push(id);
      });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The out put is `key1: ["value1c"]` since `key` in an object is unique, so it is creating key and storing only latest value. You can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and check if `myObject` has any key by that name. If so then push the value, else create a key value pair and add `id` to it

```
$(res).each(function(i, v) {
  var name = v.name;
  var id = v.id;
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    myObject[name].push(id);
  } else {
    myObject[name] = [id];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You create another array each time with this line :

```
myObject[name] = new Array();
```

So you delete the old pushed value each time.

Use a condition to initialize your array if not exist :

```
!Array.isArray(myObject[name]) && (myObject[name] = new Array());
```

e.g.

```js
$(res).each(function(i, v) {
      var name = v.name;
      var id = v.id;
      // create object with building block and tech id to associate techs to BBs
      !Array.isArray(myObject[name]) && (myObject[name] = new Array()); 
      myObject[name].push(id);
});
```